# Flask to only allow access to page internally

Tags: python, nginx, flask, restful-authentication

I'm building a `RESTful API` using `Flask` and currently have two pages (a `login` page and a `index` page).

The `index` page should only be accessible after a user has logged in.

Currently I have:

```
@app.route('/venue/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        venue_owner_email = request.form['username']
        venue_owner_password = request.form['password']

        with contextlib.closing(DBSession()) as session:
            try:
                venue = session.query(Venue).filter_by(venue_owner_email=venue_owner_email).first()
                if not venue or not pwd_context.verify(venue_owner_password, venue.venue_owner_password):
                    error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
                else:
                    return redirect(url_for('index'))                                                                                   
            except exc.SQLAlchemyError, error:
                session.rollback()
                raise_database_error(error)

    return render_template('login.html', error=error)


@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Currently `index.html` is accessible through `/` but I only want it to be accessed via `/venue/login` and not directly from the browser.

If I use the decorator `@auth.login_required`, when the `redirect` occurs, the `user` has to re-enter their credentials. Is there a way to send the `HTTP Authorisation Header` when `redirecting`?

I also thought rather than use `redirect`, I might just use `render_template` but I don't know if this is the right way to do it.

Any help on how to properly go about this would be appreciated.

Comment: check if session is present in ('/'), if not, redirect to login with a 304 code

Comment: @Sidmeister As I'm trying to follow `REST` principles should I be storing `sessions` on the server?

Comment: session is not stored in server. Setting sessions, you basically store the values in cookie(s) in client side. Store some credential for logged in user and perform necessary checks. For a bit more security, I will suggest replacing the random string in every request. Or you can employ custom tactics to deter forgery.

Comment: Just want to clarify: I shouldn't protect the route with `HTTP Auth Headers`?Also how would I prevent access to the page directly through `@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])`?

Answer (score 3):

You can add a **decorator** to `index.html` that checks the referring url. If the referring url is `/venue/login` you should serve the page else return an error.

```
if request.referrer == <venue login url>:
    # continue
 else:
    # return error message
```